# Wrong input numbers in EditText filed when use hard keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have EditText field with android:numeric="decimal" and  android:inputType="phone"  for entering decimal numbers. I use input type phone because it is more easy to user enter numbers.

For any device with soft keyboard I haven't any problem but when I begin use hard keyboard when will print wrong numbers (for example when I use HTC Desire Z).

How to solve this problem?

P.S. I developed the "[Simple Loan Calculator](http://code.google.com/p/android-simple-loan-calculator/)" for Android - it's opensource and freeware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" >
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    setPriceInputFilter(amountEdit, interestEdit, fixedPaymentEdit, periodYearEdit, periodMonthEdit, downPaymentEdit, disposableCommissionEdit, monthlyCommissionEdit);
    ....
}
private void setPriceInputFilter(EditText ... fields){
  PriceInputFilter filter = new PriceInputFilter();
  for (EditText field: fields){
    field.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
  }
}
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if(newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO){
       setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL, amountEdit, interestEdit, fixedPaymentEdit, periodYearEdit, 
                                         periodMonthEdit, downPaymentEdit, disposableCommissionEdit, monthlyCommissionEdit);
       Toast.makeText(this, "HARD-keyboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
      setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE, amountEdit, interestEdit, fixedPaymentEdit, periodYearEdit, 
                                               periodMonthEdit, downPaymentEdit, disposableCommissionEdit, monthlyCommissionEdit);
      Toast.makeText(this, "SOFT-keyboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
private void setInputType(int type , EditText ... fields){
    for (EditText field: fields){
      field.setInputType(type);
    }
}
```

**PriceInputFilter.java**

```
public class PriceInputFilter implements InputFilter {
  public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,  Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    String checkedText = dest.toString() + source.toString();
    String pattern = getPattern();
    if (!Pattern.matches(pattern, checkedText)) {
      return "";
    }
    return null;
  }
  private String getPattern() {
    return "[0-9]+([.]{1}||[.]{1}[0-9]{1,2})?";
  }
}
```